# php check if time is between range

Tags: php, timespan

I am looking for a way to check if a time is within a certain time range.

Example:
Time span: 22:30 to 04:20

How can I easily check with php if for example 13:23 is in between?

It is only about the time, the current day should not play a role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by defining two cases:

- same day. Then Tx is between T1 and T2 if T1 <= Tx and Tx <= T2.
- different days. Then Tx is between T1 and T2 if T1 <= Tx **or** Tx <= T2.

How to tell between the two cases: if T1 < T2, then same day. Else different days.

Edge case: is 21:30 between 20:30 and 20:31 **of the next day**? Of course yes. But the two cases, "20:30 of one day to 20:31 of the same day" and "20:30 of one day and 20:31 of the next day" are **indistinguishable**, so there is the possibility - depending on where your times are coming from - that **whatever test you design, it will nonetheless fail**.

Of course, if you're always in the "same day" scenario, then this error will never occur - but you won't be able to accept the "22:30 to 04:20" example in your question.

```
function between($time, $time1, $time2) {
    if ($time1 < $time2) {
        // same day
        // 09:30 <= 10:27 <= 12:15  : $time is between
        return ($time1 <= $time) && ($time <= $time2);
    }
    // time1 is day1, time2 is next day
    // 22:30 <= 23:30 or 02:15 <= 04:30: both 22:30 and 02:15
    // are in the [ 22:30...04:30 ] range
    // 06:27 is neither >= 23:30 nor <= 02:15, so is out of range
    return ($time1 <= $time) || ($time <= $time2);
}
```